# MAC New Look Outlook Failing GRAPH APIs

Tags: macos, outlook, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-web-addins, microsoft-graph-mail

We have an Outlook addin that has been working perfectly fine with the MAC Outlook's classic view. Unfortunately however, it is failing with the "new look" Outlook for MAC. With the "new look" Outlook for MAC, our GRAPH/API calls are blocked with an HTTP error 403. I think REST-APIs have the same issue with the new-look MAC Outlook as well.

Has anyone experienced (and resolved) this HTTP-403 error (for addins) in the new look MAC Outlook? Are there some settings we need to tweak to get this resolved?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Is it possible for you to share your addin so that we can try to repro this at our end?

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT Sorry for the late response. We were trying to resolve this on our own but still no progress. The server is Exchange Online, and the domain/mail server is not ours so I don't have an account/environment where it can work for you. The issue is that the REST/GRAPH/APIs work successfully when MAC is in the legacy mode. But once it goes to the new look outlook, the addin loads but the APIs fail to execute with error 403. Thank you.